# add html to div with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, string

I am trying to add some additional html to a div with id slideshow using jQuery. My code:

```
$("#slideshow").append("<a id="prev" title="Previous Slide">Previous Slide</a><a id="next" title="Next Slide">Next Slide</a>");
```

This isn't working, can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: David I use Coda for Mac thats an IDE right? but it doesn't show any errors for the mistake I just made.

Comment: I've never used coda. But it won't necessarily tell you there is an error...rather, you should be able to see that the text within your string isn't all the same color.

Comment: The fact that you're trying to append 1 string and it shows up multiple colors means it's most likely wrong.  I'm not familiar with Coda but it may just be a fancy text editor (which may be all you need.  IDEs are more powerful but they're often slower)

Comment: Just shows them red regardless of type might see if can find an add-on that deals with this. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You're mixing quotes.

Your string goes from the first `"` to the second `"`, meaning that the string only contains `"<a id="`.  The string is followed by the identifier `prev`, then another string, creating a syntax error.

Change the outer quotes around the string to `'`, like this:

```
'<a id="prev" title="Previous Slide">Previous Slide</a><a id="next" title="Next Slide">Next Slide</a>'
```

Comment: Ahhh I always wondered about that. I have seen both types used before. so I should always use ' and not " like this $('#slides') and not $("slides")?

Comment: I like to use the single quotes in js, it seems more readable - then if you're appending in html you can stick with the double quotes mostly.

Comment: That's a matter of personal preference. Just don't use both in the same line of code or else they'll conflict.

Comment: In Javascript (unlike other languages), there is no difference whatsoever between `'Hi!'` and `"Hi!"`.  (Except for which quotes need to be escaped)

Comment: Just make sure what you're using for outer quotes is different from what you're using for inner quotes. If you have inner-inner quotes then you'll probably need to escape them and it gets real ugly.

Comment: @mtwallet: You should always use one or the other...it is personal preference. I tend towards this: `"<div></div>"` and `"<div class='foo bar'>David's div</div>"`. Where the double quotes are used on the outside and single quotes inside the string.

Answer (score 2):

your not escaping your quotes best way to fix is to put the append in single quotes

```
$("#slideshow").append('<a id="prev" title="Previous Slide">Previous Slide</a><a id="next" title="Next Slide">Next Slide</a>');
```