# Output html to <div> using jquery

Tags: jquery, css, html

I have a dropdown menu and i want to display the html contents of the button link to a `<DIV>`
Does anyone know how to do such?
Do you have a sample page i can refer?
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: What do you mean by dropdown button ??

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We encourage you to [research your questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). If you've [tried something already](http://whathaveyoutried.com/), please add it to the question - if not, research and attempt your question first, and then come back.

Comment: This should be pretty simple if you read up on the basics of http://jquery.com/

Comment: Don't worry!) Everything is experience!)

Comment: Thanks for understanding. i'm new to this stuff. I tried checking on some tutorials and just wanted to try if i can get more info from here. :)

Answer (score 1):

When searching Google for [jquery add html to div](https://www.google.be/search?q=jquery+add+html+to+div&aq=f&sugexp=chrome,mod=4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) these are the first two links:

- [append](http://api.jquery.com/append/): Insert content, specified by the parameter, to the end of each element in the set of matched elements.
- [html](http://api.jquery.com/html/): Get the HTML contents of the first element in the set of matched elements.

Fourth link is a duplicate: [add html to div with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2774091/540352) where there is an example of `append()`.

First Googling your question does not only save our time, you actually get your answers faster. If Google turns up dry or you need more information, THEN you come to SO and many users here will be happy to help you.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks dude.. noted on this. appreciate the advice :)

Answer (score 1):

Well, just reading your code (no code) you can set the html of a DOM element with:

```
$("DIV").html("HERE");
$("DIV").append("HERE");
something.appendTo("DIV");
```

for getting something specific from a element you can use: `$("DIV").attr("attribute of the element");`

Answer (score 0):

I hope this may be helpful to you

```
 <div class="dropdown">
<a class="account" >My Account</a>
<div class="submenu">
<ul class="root">
<li ><a href="#Dashboard" >Dashboard</a></li>
<li ><a href="#Profile" >Profile</a></li>
<li ><a href="#settings">Settings</a></li>
<li ><a href="#feedback">Send Feedback</a></li>
</ul>
</div>

</div>
```

Domo page: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sselvamani22/z2cyk/)

Sample page: [website](http://www.9lessons.info/2012/06/simple-drop-down-menu-with-jquery-and.html)